# Deleting an object used as key in dict does not remove the correspondent key in the dict

Tags: python, dictionary, instance

I have a dictionary that has object instance as keys:

```
outputs = {instance1:instance1.id, instance2:instance2.id}
```

When I delete the object from outside the dict, the correspondent key is not deleted from the dictionary, which is not what I expected.

What I wanted to achieve is that when the object is deleted from outside the dict, the key also disappear from the dict.

Comment: What do you mean by deleting the object? Show us the code that doesn't work.

Comment: Thats because instance1 or instance2 are not referenced in a dictionary instead their hash is computed and stored for look up.

Comment: The reference count for those objects cannot fall to zero, *because* you have references to them in the dictionary. If you need different behaviour, make the key a [weak reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html).

Comment: Why do you need a map to look up the id of an instance? Can't you just access instance.id?

Comment: Perhaps you want a [WeakKeyDictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakKeyDictionary)?  You haven't defined what you mean by "deleting an object from outside the dict".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact your object stored in a variable and the object used as key in the dictionary are not exactly the same. They are two different references to the same object in the memory.

Let's take the following example:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, _repr):
        self._repr = _repr

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self._repr, id(self))

 a = Foo('f1')
 # The count returned by getrefcount() is generally one higher than you might expect, because it includes the (temporary) reference as an argument to getrefcount()
 print(sys.getrefcount(a) - 1) # Out: 1
 d = {a: 'value'} # Out {f1-139822435732560: 'value'}
 print(sys.getrefcount(a) - 1) # Out: 2
 a._repr = 'f2'
 print(d) # Out {f2-139822435732560: 'value'}
```

Which prouves the dict created a new reference to the main object. And because Python's main method of memory management uses reference counting :

> Python keeps a count of all the references to 
>   the object, and when there are none left, the object is deleted.

so if you delete the reference stored in the varaiable `del a`, the reference stored in the dict stayed.

```
del a
print(sys.getrefcount(d.keys()[0]) - 1) # Out: 1
```

And this will make inconstancy in you dict because you have any more access to your data, I will recommend to use the variable reference to delete the data from the dict than delete the object.

```
del d[a]
print(sys.getrefcount(a) - 1) # Out: 1
del a
```

Answer (score 1):

before deleting the object, you have to delete the key from the dictionary.

```
del outputs[instance1]
```

this happens because the dict doesn't store the object as the key, but a hash that is generated from it.